# concatenate N number of string

Tags: java, android

I Am new to the Android,I need to send an sms which will Contain the following content
e.g: "1"+"\n"+"f_name"+"l_name"+"roll";i am storing these information in arraylist.can anyone suggest me how to perform the operation.i have done some operations.

```
try {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        System.out.println("RN-->>created parser");
        SAXXMLHandlerChalanForm ch = new SAXXMLHandlerChalanForm();
        xr.setContentHandler(ch);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("Chalan.xml")));

        ArrayList<ChalanFormDTO> chalanList = ch.getChalanData();
        System.out.println("size of ChalanList" + chalanList.size());



        for (int i = 0; i < chalanList.size(); i++) {

        if (chalanNum.equalsIgnoreCase(chalanList.get(i).getChalanNo())) 
                   {                             text_chalanNo.setText(chalanList.get(i).getChalanNo());



                text_buyName.setText(chalanList.get(i).getBuyerName());

                text_date.setText(chalanList.get(i).getDates());

                text_sales.setText(chalanList.get(i).getSales());
                System.out.println("Size of LISTOFITEMS:\n"
                        + chalanList.get(i).getListOfStock().size());
                for (int j = 0; j < chalanList.get(i).getListOfStock()
                        .size(); j++) {
                    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
                    tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    TextView tv9 = new TextView(this);
                    tv9.setText(String.valueOf(j+1));
                    tv9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_top);
                    tv9.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
                    tv9.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(dpwidth/2,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv9.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    tv9.setMinimumWidth(dpwidth);
                    tr1.addView(tv9);


                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
                    tv4.setText(chalanList.get(i).getListOfStock().get(j)
                            .getName());
                    tv4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_top);
                    tv4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
                    tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(dpwidth,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    tv4.setMinimumWidth(dpwidth);
                    tr1.addView(tv4);

                    TextView tv6 = new TextView(this);
                    tv6.setText(chalanList.get(i).getListOfStock().get(j)
                            .getQuantity());
                    tv6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_top);
                    tv6.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
                    tv6.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(dpwidth,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    tv6.setMinimumWidth(dpwidth);
                    tr1.addView(tv6);
                    table.addView(tr1, 3);

                }

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: Give real example of this expression:"1"+"\n"+"f_name"+"l_name"+"roll", I mean how exactly you want in output!

Comment: as from my code :for the outside For Loop:
'1
12-12-2013
sbs pvt. ltd.
salesForce

Inside For Loop:

stk1 shree prod 1200
stk2 shree_food 1890'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the arraylist data inside a stringbuffer using a for loop.

create a stringbuffer like

```
StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0; i<chalanList.size; i++)
{
     strbuf.append("1\n");
     strbuf.append("f_name: "+chalanList.get(i).f_name);
     strbuf.append(chalanList.get(i).getChalanNo());
     strbuf.append(chalanList.get(i).getBuyerName());
     . . .
}
```

after your insertion is complete send it to sms.